# Unknown attribute when saving a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, attributes, nested

I'm writing an engine with Rails 3. And I have there a generic_recipe which contains recipes like this:

```
module EdibleRecipe
  class GenericRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :recipe, :recipe_attributes, ....
    has_many :recipes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes 
  end
end
```

The form renders correctly with:

```
<%= f.fields_for :recipe do |r| %>
...
```

But when saving, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in EdibleRecipe::GenericRecipesController#create
```

[Full code is here](https://github.com/valk/edible-recipe). Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Another issue was that I had f.fields_for :recipe instead of  f.fields_for :recipes in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
attr_accessible :recipes_attributes
```

Instead of :recipe_attributes